# Database : Primary key columns in beginning of table

Tags: sql-server, oracle, db2

Dos it impact having all the primary key columns at the beginning of the table?

I know partial index reads most likely involve table scans that brings whole row into buffer pool for predicate matching. I am curious to know any performance gain having primary keys at the top of the table would provide.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**In Oracle, the order of the columns of a table has little impact in general on performance**.

The reason is that all columns of a row are generally contained on a single block and that the difference in time between finding the first column and the last column of a row in a block is infinitesimal compared to finding/reading the block.

Furthermore, when you reach the database block to read a row, the primary key may not be the most important column.

Here are a few exceptions where column order might have an impact:

- when you have > 255 columns in your table, the rows will be split in two blocks (or more). Accessing the first 255 columns may be cheaper than accessing the remaining columns.
- the last columns of a row take 0 byte of space if they are `NULL`. As such, columns that contain many `NULL` values are best left at the end of a row if possible to reduce space usage and therefore IO. In general the impact will be minimal since other NULL columns take 1 byte each so the space saved is small.
- when compression is enabled, the efficiency of the compression may depend upon the column order. A good rule of thumb would be that columns with few distinct values should be grouped to enhance the chance that they will be merged by the compression algorithm.
- You should think about the order of columns when you use [Index Organized Table](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_7002.htm#i2128766) (IOT) with the [overflow clause](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_7002.htm#i2128810). With this clause, all columns after a determined dividing column will be stored out of line and accessing them will incur additional cost. Primary keys are always stored physically at the beginning of the rows in IOT.

Comment: Actually, if you a put `NON NULL` column (such as a pk) at the end, all nullable columns will have their space allocated. This behavior appears with varchar2, not number. I dunno about other types.

Comment: @Plouf - this presumes that the RDBMS isn't re-ordering columns (in actual storage, not in definition) so that all non-null columns appear first - and this is a trivial optimization.  Now, knowing _which_ nullable column to put first is important, based on which columns will most-often be populated...

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse Yep, but Oracle does not do this _trivial optimization_, so I think it is worth mentioning it. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/438ff/2

Comment: @plouf Something was wrong with your SQLFiddle, see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/beaea/1 , I'm not sure what you are trying to prove though. Also this *trivial* optimization (1) may be detrimental for all the reasons I listed (compression, ease of access for full scan, etc, etc) and (2) will have such a minor impact as to not matter anyhow that's why Oracle won't reorder the columns. Also VARCHAR2 are **variable**-length, Oracle only allocates the space needed, never more.

Comment: @VincentMalgrat Well, I'm confused. I probably have to check back a few things.

Answer (score 0):

At least in SQL Server there is no performance benefit based on the order of the columns in the table, primary key or not.  The only benefit to having your primary key columns at the top of the list is organizational.  Kind of like having a table with these columns Id, FirstName, LastName, Address1, Address2, City, State, Zip.  It's a lot easier to follow in that order than Address2, State, Firstname, Id, Address1, Lastname, Zip, City.  I don't know much about Oracle or DB2 but I believe it's the same.

Answer (score 0):

In DB2, (and I think the answers about the other database manager systems should check the answers) the columns that have less modification should be at the beginning of each row, because when performing an update it takes from the first modified column till the end of the row, to write that in the transaction logs.

It only impacts the update operation, inserts, delete or select do not have problems. And the impact is that the IO is a little reduced, because less information should be written if just the last columns have to be written. This could be important when performing updates over a few small columns on tables with big rows with lots of record. If the first column is modified, DB2 will write the whole row.

Ordering columns to minimize update logging: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.dbobj.doc/doc/c0024496.html

Answer (score 0):

(for ORACLE)
Is it fair to say then, that any and all primary key columns, even if there is just 1, should be the first or among the first few columns in a row.  Further, tagging them on the END of the row is bad practice, particularly after a series of possibly/likely null attribute fields?

Thus, a row like:

pkcol(s), att1,att2,att3, varchar2(2000)

is better organized for all the reasons stated above than

att1, att2, att3, varchar2(2000), pkcol(s)

Why am I asking? Well, don't judge, but we are simplifying the PK for some tables and the developers have happily tagged the new GUID pk (don' judge #2) onto the end of the row.  I am bothered by this but need some feedback to justify my fears.  Also does this matter at all for SQL Server?