# cant import the table( invalid datatype)

Tags: sql, oracle

```
CREATE TABLE training (
    coach_id int NOT NULL,
    customer_id int NOT NULL,
    training_time_start time  NULL,
    training_time_end time  NULL,
    training_place_id int NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT training_pk PRIMARY KEY (training_place_id)
);
```

> Error report - ORA-00902: invalid datatype
> 00902. 00000 -  "invalid datatype"
> *Cause:
> *Action:

I would like to know where is a mistake. im using oracle connection.

Comment: `time` isn't a data type in Oracle. You seem to have a script that is intended for another DBMS. You can go use that other DBMS or translate the script. But the latter needs more deeper knowledge about what the script does and the database models. That is too broad for a single question on this site.

Comment: You could have easily checked the documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/Data-Types.html#GUID-7B72E154-677A-4342-A1EA-C74C1EA928E6

Comment: Tip: remove columns one by one and find a problematic row. Then do the same for constraints on that column unless you have `<column_name> <datatype>` or the error is gone. Then you can easily check the documentation on constraint definition or datatypes and column naming rules. This way is 10 times faster than asking syntax error questions on SO.

Comment: the problem is in that training_time_start, training_time_end
how can I fix it, any idea?
also, I'm only studying

Comment: @ЮраЯрмак the issue is already explained in the comments by @stickybit and @EdStevens. What is this `time` type the code refers to?

Answer (score 1):

Here's one suggestion.

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE training(
  2    training_place_id    INT,
  3    coach_id             INT NOT NULL,
  4    customer_id          INT NOT NULL,
  5    training_time_start  DATE,
  6    training_time_end    DATE,
  7    --
  8    CONSTRAINT training_pk PRIMARY KEY (training_place_id)
  9  );

Table created.

SQL>
```

Modifications made to your code:

- obviously, `DATE` was used (instead of non-existent TIME datatype)
- I moved `TRAINING_PLACE_ID` "up". Why? I prefer so, so that primary key column(s) are placed at the top of the column list. Why? They can't be `NULL` so it is certain that those columns will always have a value. Not that it largely improves performance, though (see what @Vincent said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14984695/database-primary-key-columns-in-beginning-of-table))

  - as it is a primary key column, you can (but don't have to) specify that it is `NOT NULL`. Oracle will do it for you anyway:

    ```
    SQL> desc training
     Name                          Null?    Type
     ----------------------------- -------- --------------------
     TRAINING_PLACE_ID             NOT NULL NUMBER(38)
     <snip>
    ```

Although you didn't specify it, it looks as if the `training` table lacks in two foreign keys on `coach_id` and `customer_id` columns